# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status jquery.js.jsf of 400

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets, primefaces

I am trying to send some images via Ajax POST request using jQuery but I am having 400 bad request error.

Here is my code:

```
function sendImages(param, dados){
    var p = document.getElementById('frm:p').textContent;
    param = param + "_" + p;
    $.post('/app_context/Servlet/' + param, dados, function(data,status,xhr){
        if(data === 'END'){
            doThis();
        }
    });
}
```

The js files are imported like this, all inside of h:head /h:head:

```
<meta name="copyright" content="some text here"/>
<link href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/css/primefaces.css" rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"/>
<link href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../images/favicon.ico"/>
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head"/>
<script src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/js/default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the console of Chrome, this is printed:

[image: chrome console error]

Comment: what kind of html element is `<outputScript>`?? Never heard of it. EDIT: ok no experience with servlets, but shouldn't that be `<h:outputScript ...` ??

Comment: Yes. @Juan Carlos Mendoza incorrectly edited this.